# How to run a method, while sending a heartbeat, and get the return value of the method

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've got one method which calls a bunch of tools which may or may not finish running in a timely fashion. I would like to be able to send a heartbeat back to a server to tell it that we're still running, and check if we've run out of time.

The code looks something like this:

```
class Worker:

    def run:
        proc = Process(target=_execute, args=(foo, bar, ))
        proc.start()
        while True:
            if proc.is_alive():
                if not _heart_beat():
                    # Server told us to stop, kill the _execute process.
                    proc.terminate()
                    break
            else:
                # _execute is done, we can stop sending heartbeats
                break
            time.sleep(beat_interval)

    def _execute(foo, bar):
        #exec /bin/foo
        #exec /bin/bar
        #do something with their output
        return foo_bar
```

This works for me, but I'd like to be able to get the return value of `_execute`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `instance member` to store the result:

```
class Worker(object):  # inherit from object - python-2.7
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = None

    def run(self):
        ...
        else: # process finished
            return self.result

    def _execute(self, foo, bar):
        # run foo and bar
        self.result = foo_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Queue`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def _execute(q, foo, bar):
    # do stuff
    q.put(return_value)

... class etc...
def run():
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=_execute args=(q, foo, bar))
    p.start()
    while True:
        if proc.is_alive():
            if not _heart_beat():
                # Server told us to stop, kill the _execute process.
                proc.terminate()
                break
        else:
            return_code = q.get()
            break
        ... etc ...
```